# How to get a user by its parameters on firestore/firebase to get antother parameter

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build my first app using react native and javascript and I've been looking in the documentation of both, but I haven't been able to solve this problem.

I have this function that Logs in the app with the email and password that were texted in the input.

```
onSignUp(){
    const {email,password} = this.state;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) 
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch((error) => {
    alert(error)
    console.log(error)
})
}
```

But before it logs in, I wanted it to check using the email that is saved in the firestore what level has the user, so it would only go into the **signInWithEmailAndPassword** function if he had the level equal or above 1.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rInwE.png) is the link for the image of my firebase documentation body.

I was trying to do something like(raw thinking):

```
onSignUp(){
        const {email,password} = this.state;
        userID= get('users') where ('email' == email)

        userLevel = get(userLevel) from (userID)

        if(userLevel>=1){
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) 
            ....
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated, I looked in the documentation, tried a few things but no positive outcome.

Comment: That won't really work; I think you can either (a) let them log it, or (b) not allow new sign-ups, to prevent new users from signing in. If you choose (a) you can log in and then get a user level, and then focus on limiting functionality based on that level.

Comment: As @Aadmaa said, I think the best approach you can use is to implement the logic to login the user (validate credentials) and once you have logged in the user, look for their level and apply the right logic